# RoR: Nested Forms Model attributes inside other model attributes

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

i'm making a project where a "Project has_many tasks, and TASK has Task1, task1 has task 2 and task2 has task3. "

But im stuck in making a way to INSERT all those tasks in just one form,

im using nested form gem,

This is what i thought'd work.

```
def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:projeto_id, :raiz, :descr, :hour, :typo, :tsk1s_attributes => [:raiz, :descr, :hour, :typo, :_destroy, :tsk2s_attributes => [:raiz, :descr, :hour, :typo, :_destroy, :tsk3s_attributes => [:raiz, :descr, :hour, :typo, :_destroy]]])
end
```

task.erb model

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :tsk1s
  belongs_to :projeto
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :tsk1s, allow_destroy: true
 end
```

tsk1.erb model

```
class Tsk1 < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :task
  has_many :tsk2s
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :tsk2s, allow_destroy: true
end
```

same for tsk2.erb, tsk3 only belongs_to

a piece of my form bellow, this is for adding the tsk2, tsk3 is same and tsk1 too.

```
<%= f.fields_for :tsk2s do |tsk2| %>
   <ul class="step">
   <li>
   <%=  tsk2.number_field :raiz, :placeholder => "Identificador" %> 
   <%=  tsk2.text_field :descr, :placeholder => "Descrição" %> 
   <%=  tsk2.number_field :hour, :placeholder => "Carga Horária" %> 
   <%= tsk2.select("typo", {"Analitica" => "Analitica", "Sintetica" => "Sintetica"}) %>
     <%= tsk2.link_to_remove "-" %>  
    <%= f.link_to_add "+Galho", :tsk3s %> </li>
   <% end %>
```

This actually only saves task and tsk1 attributes,

task controller:

```
 def create
@task = Task.new(task_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @task.save
    format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

```
 def new
@task = Task.new
```

end

full form code http://pastebin.com/DSwZGfNs

Comment: Please update your post with `new` and `create` methods of your controller. And also with full form code.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason could be in your form code, `:tsk2s`, `:tsk3s` are nested in ***tasks*** but as per the model code, `:tsk2s` should be nested in `:tsk1s` and `:tsk3s` should be nested in `:tsk2s`.

Change your form accordingly like below

```
  <%= f.fields_for :tsk1s do |tsk1| %>

  <ul>
  <li>
  <%= tsk1.number_field :raiz, :placeholder => "Identificador" %>
  <%= tsk1.text_field :descr, :placeholder => "Descrição"  %>
  <%= tsk1.number_field :hour , :placeholder => "Carga Horária" %>
  <%= tsk1.select("typo", {"Analitica" => "Analitica", "Sintetica" => "Sintetica"}) %>
  <%= f.link_to_add "+Ramo", :tsk2s %>
  <%= tsk1.link_to_remove "-" %> </li>

  <%= tsk1.fields_for :tsk2s do |tsk2| %>

  <ul class="step">
  <li>
  <%= tsk2.number_field :raiz, :placeholder => "Identificador" %>
  <%= tsk2.text_field :descr, :placeholder => "Descrição" %>
  <%= tsk2.number_field :hour, :placeholder => "Carga Horária" %>
  <%= tsk2.select("typo", {"Analitica" => "Analitica", "Sintetica" => "Sintetica"}) %>
  <%= tsk2.link_to_remove "-" %>  
  <%= f.link_to_add "+Galho", :tsk3s %> </li>

  <%= tsk2.fields_for :tsk3s do |tsk3| %>

  <ul>
  <li>  

  <%= tsk3.number_field :raiz, :placeholder => "Identificador" %>
  <%= tsk3.text_field :descr, :placeholder => "Descrição" %>
  <%= tsk3.number_field :hour, :placeholder => "Carga Horária" %>
  <%= tsk3.select("typo", {"Analitica" => "Analitica", "Sintetica" => "Sintetica"}) %>
  <%= tsk3.link_to_remove "-" %> </li>
  </ul>
  </ul>
  </ul>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <% end &>
  </ul>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <%= f.link_to_add "+Raiz", :tsk1s %> <br> <br> <br>
  <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Got this error, Unpermitted parameters: 1436559009615, new_tsk1s

"task"=>{"projeto_id"=>"1", "raiz"=>"1", "descr"=>"asd", "hour"=>"33", "typo"=>"Analitica", "tsk1s_attributes"=>{"1436559009615"=>{"raiz"=>"2", "descr"=>"gf", "hour"=>"5", "typo"=>"Analitica", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "new_tsk1s"=>{"tsk2s_attributes"=>{"1436559010833"=>{"raiz"=>"3", "descr"=>"h", "hour"=>"5", "typo"=>"Analitica", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "new_tsk2s"=>{"tsk3s_attributes"=>{"1436559011808"=>{"raiz"=>"4", "descr"=>"b", "hour"=>"5", "typo"=>"Analitica", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}}}}}, "commit"=>"Create Task"}